# Удалить все после 3 символа DelphiXE

Tags: delphi

**Сделала вот такой вод:** Удаление всего текста, в строке - после символа **"/"**.

```
  for i:=0 to St.Count-1 do begin // Цикл
          Delete(s, Pos('/', s), Length(s));
          end;
```

**Подскажите:** Как добавить условие - удаление всего после 3 символа **"/"**.

**К примеру, если в строке, текст такого плана:**
/111пример1/222пример2/333пример3

**То результат:**
/111пример1/222пример2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
procedure DeleteAfterThirdSlash(var s: string);
var 
  iChar, slashCount: integer;
begin
  slashCount := 0;
  for iChar := 1 to Length(s) do 
  begin
    if s[iChar] = '/' then
      Inc(slashCount);
    if slashCount = 3 then
    begin
      Delete(s, iChar + 1, Length(s) - iChar);
      break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Igor, Как всегда, Вы - на высоте. Очень профессиональные решения!

Comment: Последний вопрос, по этой теме: А как удалить и сам символ "/". ?

Comment: @Татьяна `Delete(s, iChar, Length(s) - iChar + 1);`