# Как удалить указанное количество слов с конца строки в Delphi?

Tags: delphi, строки

Мой код удаляет указанное количество слов в `SpinEdit` с начала строки.

Как сделать так, чтобы удалялось указанное количество слов с конца строки?

```
var
  s: string; // Строка со словами
  i, n, a, k, q: integer;
begin
  ...
  n := 0;
  a := 0;
  q := 0;
  k := StrToInt(SpinEdit1.Text);
  i := Length(s); // считаем длину строки
{$R-}
  repeat
    Inc(a);
    if s[a] = ' ' then
      Inc(q);
    n := a;
  until k = q;
{$R+}
  Delete(s, 1, n);
```

Делала `Delete(s, 1, n);`, заменяла на `Delete(s,length(s)-k, n);`, но тогда удаляется только первое слово с конца строки (При указанном параметре, в `SpinEdit1` - два слова).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Удалить все после 3 символа DelphiXE](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/842622/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-3-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0-delphixe)

Только развернуть цикл с конца к началу:

```
for iChar := Length(s) downto 1 do
begin
  // ...
```

Comment: А вопрос iChar:integer;  А Ваш код вставить после Readln(f1, s); ?

Comment: @Татьяна Напишите отдельную функцию, как в другом ответе. Передавайте туда строку, символ и количество.

Comment: В другом вопросе это ? Ничего не поняла, извините за такой вопрос :(. Я запуталась...

Comment: @Татьяна Первая строка в ответе выше - ссылка на Ваш старый вопрос с моим ответом.